# Problema con adaptador de RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Tengo un RecyclerView de reservas cargado desde un adaptador, el resultado final es la imagen que coloco a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al querer seleccionar una opción como 'Ver Detalle' no logro obtener los datos de la entidad reserva y a partir de su id buscar el detalle de la misma. A continuación, el código del adaptador

```
public class MisReservasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MisReservasAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ReservasApi> list;
private View.OnClickListener listener;


public MisReservasAdapter(List<ReservasApi> list, Context mCtx, View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.list = list;
    Context mCtx1 = mCtx;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_reservas, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MisReservasAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ReservasApi myList = list.get(position);

    holder.txtEstado.setText(myList.getEstado());

    int idEstado = myList.getIdEstado();

    if(idEstado==2){
        holder.imgEstado.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_confirm);
    }else if(idEstado == 5){
        holder.imgEstado.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel);
    }

    holder.txtFecha.setText(myList.getFechaReserva());

    holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.txtEstado)
    public TextView txtEstado;
    @BindView(R.id.txtFecha)
    public TextView txtFecha;
    @BindView(R.id.txtOptions)
    public TextView buttonViewOption;
    @BindView(R.id.imgEstado)
    public ImageView imgEstado;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
    }
}}
```

A continuación la se crea la instancia del adaptador en el onPostExecute de un AsyncTask

```
      protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            // forma 1
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ReservasApi>>() {
            }.getType();
            final List<ReservasApi> reservas = new Gson().fromJson(s, listType);

            adapter = new MisReservasAdapter(reservas, getContext(), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //creating a popup menu
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
                    //inflating menu from xml resource
                    popup.inflate(R.menu.options_reservas);
                    //adding click listener
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.VerDetalle:
                                    new GetDetalleReserva().execute(3051);
                                    break;
                                case R.id.Cancelar:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cancelar todo esto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.show();
                }
            });
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

la solucion a tu problema es implementar la interfaz dentro del view holder, como te he puesto en el ejemplo. Dentro del metodo public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                }, puedes colocar la logica de negocio de tu aplicacion,, ahora que ya puedes saber la vista que se ha pulsado y la posicion dentro del adaptador. O bien colocar el clickListner dentro del constructor ViewHolder asi:

```
@BindView(R.id.imgEstado)
public ImageView imgEstado;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
            imgEstado.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Para poner el item a la escucha:

```
public class MisReservasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MisReservasAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ReservasApi> list;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;


    public MisReservasAdapter(List<ReservasApi> list, Context mCtx) {
        this.list = list;
        Context mCtx1 = mCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rv_reservas, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MisReservasAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ReservasApi myList = list.get(position);

        holder.txtEstado.setText(myList.getEstado());

        int idEstado = myList.getIdEstado();

        if(idEstado==2){
            holder.imgEstado.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_confirm);
        }else if(idEstado == 5){
            holder.imgEstado.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel);
        }

        holder.txtFecha.setText(myList.getFechaReserva());

        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.txtEstado)
        public TextView txtEstado;
        @BindView(R.id.txtFecha)
        public TextView txtFecha;
        @BindView(R.id.txtOptions)
        public TextView buttonViewOption;
        @BindView(R.id.imgEstado)
        public ImageView imgEstado;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
    }
    // allows clicks events to be caught
        public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
        public interface ItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias Santiago pero no logro comprender del todo tu método, incluso lo copie tal cual y mClickListener me genera error en el onClick y en el setClickListener, y me queda la duda de donde desplegar el pop up. podrias orientarme un poco mas por favor??

Comment: Disculpa David, luego te pongo un ejemplo completo, para que lo veas. Saludos